# Cypher Query - Returning weight of each matching relationship with total weight

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find percentage in the following example

```
START n=node:name_idx(NAME="ABC")
match p = n-[r1:LIKES]->m
with r1.Frequency as Frequency, Sum(r1.Frequency) as Sum
return Frequency, Sum
```

I was hoping to get something like this

```
Frequency        Sum
12               19
6                19
1                19
```

and so forth.

What I get is same value in Frequency and Sum columns

```
 Frequency        Sum
    12               12
    6                6
    1                1
```

Any suggestions how to get correct distribution? My ultimate goal is to find out the percentage by dividing Frequency/Sum of reach returning row. Thanks

Comment: Could you put up a small subset on http://console.neo4j.org ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this one (I stole Luanne's console graph):

http://console.neo4j.org/r/3axtkq

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name="a") 
MATCH n-[r1:LIKES]->m 
WITH sum(r1.frequency) AS total, n // we want the total... of all frequencies for n
MATCH n-[r1:LIKES]->m              // we need to get the likes again, because those can't be passed in with and get the total of all at the same time
RETURN r1.frequency, total, r1.frequency/(total*1.0) // it does integer math unless you force one to be a float
```

Comment: Ah that is what was asked for. My bad, misunderstood

Comment: This is one of those cases where I'd rather have a collect/unwind functionality instead of going back to match.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://console.neo4j.org/r/voavd2

The data is:

```
 START n=node(1)
 MATCH n-[r1:LIKES]->m
 RETURN r1,m
```

Your query returns:

```
 START n=node(1)
 MATCH n-[r1:LIKES]->m 
 WITH r1.frequency AS Frequency, Sum(r1.frequency) AS Sum 
 RETURN Frequency, Sum
```

i.e. grouped by frequency, what is the sum of all frequencies for that value.

Is that what you were trying to get?

Comment: Agreed. +1 for providing the sample data.